# opengl glDepthRange object disappearing on Z depth

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

[image]
Lines are dissapearing when z depth increases while rotating the object around x axis by 10 degrees. I edited the glDepthRange value to -100,100 or higher but nothing changes. How can i solve this?

```
void render()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    if( gRenderQuad )
    {
        glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex3f(0.3f, 0.5f, 0.4f );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.9f );
        glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f( 0.5f, 0.5f );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f, 0.5f );
        glEnd();
    }
    glDepthRange(-100,100);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I edited the `glDepthRange` value to -100, 100

This is not possible. The values for the depth range must be in [0.0, 1.0]. You can just set a sub range of the range [0.0, 1.0]. See [`glDepthRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml).

If you want to increase the viewing volume, you need to use a projection matrix. An [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) can be set with [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -100.0, 100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: please check https://streamable.com/wcnzei. i set it to (0,1)